# Подключение по SSH через HTTP proxy с поддержкой CONNECT метода

Tags: python, ssh, proxy, paramiko

Добрый день, вот у меня есть код:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('ip', username='usr', password='pass')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('echo "LOL"')
output = stdout.readlines()[0].rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r')
print(output)
ssh.close()
```

Как мне сделать так, что бы подключение совершалось через проскси? Буду примного благодарен.

Comment: вы хотите туннелировать ssh через http прокси c поддержкой CONNECT команды или что-то другое?

Comment: Да, что бы подключение что не через мой ip, а через подключенный прокси

Comment: связанный вопрос: [How to ssh over http proxy in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10488832/4279) (резюме ответа: создайте простой TCP сокет, выполните http CONNECT, передайте созданный сокет в paramiko).